# Timer to spaw QPushButtons at random locations

Tags: c++, qt

I want to set a timer and every 30ms create a `QPushButton` at random place of the widget. I have the following code, but it doesn't work (the window title changes, while no `QPushButton`s appear):

The .h file:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

class Tbutton : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Tbutton(QWidget * parent=0);
protected:

  void timerEvent(QTimerEvent *event);

};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

The .cpp file:

```
#include <QTimer>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QPushButton>
Tbutton::Tbutton(QWidget *parent) :QWidget(parent)
{

    startTimer(30);

}

void Tbutton::timerEvent(QTimerEvent *e)
{

    Q_UNUSED(e);
      QPushButton * b1=new QPushButton("re",this);
      b1->setGeometry(rand(),rand(),20,20);
      QString abs="abs"+QString::number(rand());
      setWindowTitle(abs);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to add `b1->show()` in `timerEvent`.

Answer (score 1):

`rand()` returns an integer between `0` and `RAND_MAX`, which is typically some big value (on the VC++ CRT it's 32767, on glibc it's 2147483647); so in almost every case you are spawning buttons far away on the down/right of the window, where they aren't visible at all.

You can fix this by limiting the random range to the size of the containing window:

```
QPushButton * b1=new QPushButton("re",this);
b1->setGeometry(
    rand() % std::max((this->width()-20), 1),
    rand() % std::max((this->height()-20), 1),
    20,20);
```

Comment: Thanks, but something is still wrong. Even simple   `QPushButton * b1=new QPushButton("re",this);
      b1->setGeometry(10,10,20,20);` doesn't create a button at (10,10)

Comment: @parsecer: wait, how big is this `Tbutton`? To behave as you expect it should be the "main widget" (or, at least, a "big" widget) inside the main window.

Comment: I don't know... All the code I have is there... Looks big enough... Should I inherit from QMainWindow instead of QWidget?

Comment: Well, if this is your top level window probably you should... How exactly are you showing this window? Can you post the whole program?

Comment: added main.cpp. The window is showed simply using `Tbutton w; w.show`;